# Having trouble understanding the syntax of the <> in the code List<string>

Tags: c#

Just learning C# and I feel like I definitely have a decent grasp of it except for this one concept below.

`List<string>`.

I've been playing around with c# classes, objects, functions etc.. and have never come across anything with the `List<string>`.

I noticed this syntax used in Unity as well.

What does this syntax mean and when should I use it?

Cheers!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics

Comment: Noice David. I didn't even know what to search too understand it. I'll give it a read. Thanks man!

Comment: The keywords you are looking for are "generic types".  The notion of generic types exists in other languages as well (if you are curious).